# How to disable a Typo3 Backend "System" menu item like the Install Tool?

Tags: typo3, backend, typo3-6.2.x

the only method I know, yet, is to deinstall the Install Tool. But what I exactly want to do is just disable that menu item. It should not be just hidden by CSS, it should not even load the HTML. But the Install Tool itself should be accessible through the direct URL input.

This is currently Typo3 Version 6.2.3.

Answer (score 2):

Although this makes little sense as the install tool is accessible for admin users only and you need a completely separate password for it, you could try to remove in menu entry from the array that defines the menu.

The backend modules are registered into a global array. You can remove the entry from there (via an extension or via the `typo3conf/AdditionalConfiguration.php`. The key is `$GLOBALS['TBE_MODULES']`.
This is how it looks in my installation:

```
$TBE_MODULES['system'] = 'BeuserTxBeuser,InstallInstall,dbint,config,ReportsTxreportsm1,txschedulerM1,BelogLog';
```

Comment: This looks like it's what I'm searching but it doesn't seem to work for me. I have added the file and set the GLOBALS-TBE_MODULES-system to the same value without "InstallInstall". No changes yet. Some method to activate that? Deleted all caches in the BE.

Comment: Please use the configuration module to verify that your configuration is actually active. Make sure the clear system caches (`typo3temp/Caches`) if you change `ext_tables.php` stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two possibilities:

1. use editor accounts instead admin accounts for that - there you can disable different menu items as you wish
2. uninstall all corresponding system extensions so the menu will be empty (e.g. beuser, em, ...)

Comment: Thanks, these are valid options and one would be my choice if things were different. At the moment, I have to be admin and the Install Tool has to work but should not be accessible from the BE menu. I hope for editing the menu after its definition and before it's parsed into the displayed HTML, so I can just manage which menu items are shown and nothing more.